# How to compute intersection of two or more great 2-spheres on the surface of a 3-sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

Edit: As suggested in the comments i have permanently edited all previous mentions of 'great circles' and '4-D' / '3-D sphere' with '3-sphere' and '2-sphere' respectively.

Let $G_1$ be all the points on the surface of a N-sphere that satisfy the equation $\vec X \cdot  \vec V = 0$ for some unit vector $\vec V$ , where $\cdot$ is the dot product.

Similarly $G_2$ is the set of all points that satisfy the equation $\vec X\cdot \vec U = 0$ for some unit vector $\vec U$ , where $\vec U \ne \pm \vec V$.

The problem then is to find $G_1 \cap G_2$ .

When the two great 2-Sphere are defined in this manner then in 3-D computing their 2 intersections is simply $\pm \dfrac{ \vec U\times \vec V }{||\vec U \times \vec V||}$ , where $\times$ is the cross product.

But this only work in 3-D since cross product is not defined in 4-D, I am not even sure if there are only finitely many intersections like in 3-D. If there are infinitely many, then what form do they take ? Is there some equation that parametrize them ? Does the intersection become finite if you add more great 2-Spheres in the mix ?

Any help in computing this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your G_1 and G_2 are great spheres of dimension N-1 (not circles unless N = 2).

Comment: Put another way: if you start with $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2 = 1, $  then demand that both $z,w$  be zero, what have you got?

Comment: @DanAsimov  I am only using the term 'great circles' mostly by analogy to what happens in 3-D, and because i didn't feel comfortable using 'great sphere' as i have never heard anyone else use this term before, the dot product definition is really the main unambiguous thing to go by here, but i apologize for any confusion.

Comment: In ambient dimension $n,$   two vectors  normal define a  $n-2$ plane, where a basis can be found by row reducing a matrix. If, instead, you have $n-1$  vectors and want the line orthogonal to all of them, write them as rows of a square matirx and put symbols in the last row. Find the adjoint matrix, the last row of this one generates the line

Comment: Yes, please edit to change circles to great $2$-spheres. Saying 4D sphere is likewise confusing, because I’m sure you mean the $3$-sphere, the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Done! Thanks for the suggestion, and sorry for the confusion.